# Set php variable using HTML

Tags: php

I've wondered about this for a while and doubt I can do this, but is it possible to assign a PHP variable using HTML in the same way you can loop through things or do if/else statements by closing the PHP tag and writing in HTML? I don't really have an application for it; it's just curiosity. I tried searching for this but I'm not even sure what you would call it.

I do understand this can be done by making the HTML into a string. I was just curious if HTML could be read and assigned to a variable without wrapping it in quotes and essentially turning it into a PHP string (since those don't get color coded by text editors).

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { ?>
<p>Number <?php echo $i; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Obviously this doesn't work:

```
<?php $string = ?><p>Hi!</p><?php ; ?>
// And then later on in the code:
echo $string;
```

Comment: search for [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: Using HTML? You're not using HTML, you're using PHP embedded in HTML.

Comment: This works: `<?php if($string==1) { ?> <p>Hi!</p> <?php } ;?>`

Comment: "but is it possible to assign a PHP variable using HTML" it's not possible if your file have .html extension, its possible only if a file have .php extension then u can write php and html code in.

Comment: I'm using a php file. I updated the question to be a bit more clear on why I'm wanting this. It's just for organization in my editor (Brackets).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this and just echo the HTML rather than put it in between tags. Is this what you are talking about?

```
<?php  
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
  echo "The number is: $x <br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: No. I'm aware that you can do that (sorry, I should have explained a bit better why I was doing this). I'm trying to get the code to basically 'register' as HTML to a code editor. I've been working on a plugin for a site and noticed that HTML tags don't get color coded when they are technically a php string.

Comment: You should not be using php tag in this question i think. Rather html, javascript etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html inside of a php file

```
<?php  //test.php all on one .php file.
$world ='world';

?>


<html>

Hello <? echo $world;?>

?>
```